# Нужна помощь с контрольной суммой алгоритма луна

Tags: python, алгоритм

начал изучать Python и как первый проект решил взять себе написание алгоритма Луна, Но столкнулся с проблемой я не понимаю как можно найти все возможные комбинации по алгоритму луна. Условно имея номер карты 7000 0012 2000 xxxx нужно перебать все подходящие под алгоритм луна комбинации, которые стоят на месте "xxxx" Наведите на мысль или дайте конкретное решение которое я обязательно разберу и осознаю

```
def generateCardNumber():
    result = '700000122000'
    for i in range(13, 17):
        random.seed()
        result += str(random.randint(1, 9))
        if (i % 4 == 0):
            result += ' '
    print(result)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да 10000 можно и последовательно перебрать, если что :)

Comment: Условно, я имею номер карты вида "7000 0012 2000 xxxx" Мне нужна помощь с нахождением как раз каждой комбинации которая подходит под алгоритм луна начиная с 0000 и до 9999

Comment: ну перебери в цикле все 10тыщ

Comment: @Эникейщик Дело в том, что я не особо понимаю как это реализовать с помощью цикла, только начал учиться всему. У меня есть некое решение, но импортиуя модуль "random" Как я могу вам прислать посмотреть ?

Comment: `for n in range(0,10000):` - кажется, так :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Честно говоря на мысль ни на какую не наталкивает кроме как
прикрепил к вопросу решение

Comment: а с какой целью вы используете модуль рандом? вам нужно перебрать **все** комбинации. Какое отношение к этому имеет рандом?

Comment: @Эникейщик К сожалению до меня почему-то не доходит как это сделать...

Comment: вам нужно перебрать 10000 вариантов и среди них найти удовлетворяющие условию. Для этого вам нужен цикл перебирающий все 10000 вариантов.

Comment: Я вам заранее скажу, что таких вариантов будет 1000 :) Поэтому можете просто посчитать контрольную цифру для этих 1000 вариантов

Comment: Интересно, какая именно буква пропущена в слове "**перебать**"? )))

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, тупой перебор...

```
from functools import reduce

def luhn(code):
    LOOKUP = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
    code = reduce(str.__add__, filter(str.isdigit, code))
    evens = sum(int(i) for i in code[-1::-2])
    odds = sum(LOOKUP[int(i)] for i in code[-2::-2])
    return ((evens + odds) % 10 == 0)

for i in range(0,10000):
    s = '7000 0012 2000 ' + str(i).rjust(4,'0')
    if luhn(s):
        print(s)
```

Можно и умнее - вычислять контрольную цифру, но это уже самостоятельно :)

Comment: `reduce(str.__add__, filter(str.isdigit, code))` -> `''.join(filter(str.isdigit, code))`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Эт не знаю, код алгоритма Луна я взял из Википедии :) Сам я такое не написал бы...

Comment: Википедия расстроила.